# How to get related data with GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to get the related data from other table

I have the following model structs

```
type Community struct {
    ID       string            `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name     string            `json:"name"`
    Category CommunityCategory `json:"category" gorm:"foreignKey:ID"`
}
type CommunityCategory struct {
    ID   uint32 `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

And my code to get data is something like this

```
community := Community{ID: 1}
database.Debug().Joins("CommunityCategory").First(&community)
```

With these, I get the following error `ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table \"communities\" (SQLSTATE 42P01)`

And looking at the GORM's debug log, the query is like this

```
SELECT "communities"."id","communities"."name","communities"."introduction","communities"."address","communities"."postal_code","communities"."country","communities"."address1","communities"."address2","communities"."prefecture","communities"."city","communities"."lat","communities"."lng","communities"."phone","communities"."email","communities"."external_link_1","communities"."external_link_2","communities"."image_url","communities"."access","communities"."description","communities"."contact_name","communities"."contact_phone","communities"."contact_email","communities"."is_enabled","communities"."created_at","communities"."updated_at" FROM "communities" CommunityCategory WHERE "communities"."id" = '25b1eadf-1004-40b7-b9a2-325a83bcb938' ORDER BY "communities"."id" LIMIT 1
```

Am I doing it wrong? Lol

Comment: i think i'm one step closer to get it working now. I have just changed the argument on `Joins` to `"Category"` instead of `"CommunityCategory"`. But now the executed query is like this

`SELECT "communities"."id","Category"."id" AS "Category__id","Category"."name" AS "Category__name" FROM "communities" LEFT JOIN "community_categories" "Category" ON "communities"."id" = "Category"."id" WHERE "communities"."id" = '25b1eadf-1004-40b7-b9a2-325a83bcb938' ORDER BY "communities"."id" LIMIT 1`

but now the JOINING of table is wrong. It should be `...ON communities.category_id = category.id`

Comment: you can try `database.Debug().Preload("Category").First(&community)`, but you will have to test it out to see if it will use the foreign key properly and find the data.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by defining my struct as follows. I have added a new field `CategoryID` in `Community` struct and changed the foreign key to this new field

```
type Community struct {
    ID         string            `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name       string            `json:"name"`
    CategoryID uint32
    Category   CommunityCategory `json:"category" gorm:"foreignKey:CategoryID"`
}

type CommunityCategory struct {
    ID   uint32 `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

then on query, you can perform join like this:

```
community := Community{ID: 1}
database.Model(&Community{}).Joins("Category").First(&community)
```